# New columns added to mysql reflect the same in Hive

Tags: mysql, hive, sqoop

I have table in mysql with 4 columns and 3 rows today. I have imported that data directly as a hive table.

the table test:

```
id name sal loc
1  sam  123 hyd
2  ram  234 teb
3  red  456 qer
```

Now I want to add a new column to the existing mysql table and add a new row with values for all the 5 columns. the values for the new column
for previous rows will be null.

the table test:

```
id name sal loc zip
1  sam  123 hyd null
2  ram  234 teb null
3  red  456 qer null
4  Tim  567 CA  1245
```

When we do a sqoop incremental append I am getting values only for the old columns and the new row also shows up but for only old columns.

hive table after incremental append.

```
id name sal loc
1  sam  123 hyd
2  ram  234 teb
3  red  456 qer
4  Tim  567 CA
```

Now I want the hive table to be exact as the mysql table

Can we update the hive table while we run sqoop incremental appends? If yes

How can we do that?

If no what is the best solution for my use case

Comment: Have you tried alter table add column with CASCADE just before running the incremental load with new column changes ?

Comment: @KSNidhin No I haven't tried that, does cascade apply to all tables in that database. Could you please explain what It does?

Comment: ALTER TABLE CHANGE COLUMN with CASCADE command changes the columns of a table's metadata, and cascades the same change to all the partition metadata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no state forward solution as your ddl changed use below steps.

1 You have to drop hive table and delete data from hdfs from below location "hive.metastore.warehouse.dir/table".

2 you can do directly from Sqoop import along below option to create the table again.

```
--create-hive-table
```